# How to convert string from EnumProperty to command python?

Tags: python

I have an EnumProperty declared in a context of bpy.types.PropertyGroup
The value is as follows:

```
class SceneProp(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_enum: EnumProperty (default = 'bpy.context.scene.objects', items = (('bpy.context.scene.objects', "Full object", ""), ('bpy.context.selected_objects', "Selected object" , "")))

def register():
    Scene.scene_property = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=SceneProp)
```

Now in a function i try to call this in a for loop:

```
def myFunct(self,context):

    scn_prop = context.scene.scene_property 
    for o in exec(scn_prop.my_enum): ###exec return None... 
        print(o.name)
```

And the first time I try to do an opeation like that, I don't know if the road is correct, but I found this "exec ()" but it doesn't work because it gives me the value None

Comment: try 'eval' instead of 'exec'... but not sure this way is best practice, though

Comment: Thanks Lemon, this seems to work I think this could easily be the answer to my question

Comment: This is much more a Python question than a Blender's one. If I can add about that. You should name the enum property conventionally and either use "if" if few values or a dictionary to map to some function if many.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice, in fact the question before asking it I searched on python, but I saw that the exec () command was used which for some reason (which I obviously don't know) I didn't know the command "eval ()" I don't understand if it's a problem with blender or python itself. However I will leave this command in the drawer because for now I have found another solution less "Dangerous". I think I should rate your answer, so if you want to post the answer it will be marked as an accepted answer

Comment: exec in Python always returns None. Blender uses standard Python, so there is nothing particular to Blender here.

Comment: Thanks Lemon, I still don't understand the reason for the 'None', but I have to learn a lot more about Python, thanks to people like you I'm learning a lot in practice. I'm happy about this